# How can I translate jsp:param within jsp:include to Java with RequestDispatcher.include

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, include, param

I want to translate

```
<jsp:include page="xxx.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="x" value="0"/>
</jsp:include>
```

to Java, like:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("xxx.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

How can I put the `param x = 0` ? the request doesn't have a setParameter (at least not in pre Servlet 3.0)

Something like `request.getRequestDispatcher("xxx.jsp" + "?x=0");` ?

Comment: I think your approach is correct. Are you having any issues while doing that call?

Comment: no, I don't have. But what if I already have some request parameters ?

Comment: You need to append by adding & symbol, example, xxx.jps?y=10&x=10

Comment: so first I have to see if I already have some parameters, if I have I use &, if I don't i use ?

Comment: You use exactly like how you have in question

Comment: even if I already have some parameters in my request ? or this "xxx.jsp?bla=bla" is a parameter just for the include, it does not get appended in the real request :) ?